Auto refreshing JWKs inside a ruby on rails server
Context- I am setting up a Rails server which would be responsible for validating permission for incoming HTTP requests based on their JWTs. In order to do this, I would be maintaining JWKs and use them for validation.
Problem - I would like to periodically refresh the JWKs I hold in my server.
I am coming from the Go world where auto-refresh capabilities are present in packages like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk#AutoRefresh. Is there something similar for Ruby?
I found this popular gem jwt which takes care of validations using JWT and JWK. It does not have auto-refresh capabilities though. Since this seems like such a common usecase I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already some existing solution out there.
In case there are no existing solutions for this, would also appreciate some tips for writing my own custom auto-refresh JWK solution.
